# Querying a table with multiple conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like this :

```
Date       | Product | purchases | sales  |
-----------+---------+-----------+--------+
2019-01-01 | P1      | 2         | 1      |
2019-02-01 | P2      | 2         | 1      |
2019-01-02 | P1      | 2         | 2      |
2019-08-01 | P2      | 8         | 8      |
2019-08-02 | P1      | 2         | 1      |
2019-08-03 | P2      | 8         | 8      |
```

I want a query that will get me for each product the sum of the purchases during last month, in purchases, the sum of the sales for each product during last month, in sales, in the date I want the date for last day of last month, and a new column called `Stock` that calculates for each product the sum of the purchases - the sum of the sales from the beginning until the first day of current month (meaning not just for last moth but for all time until the 2019-09-01).

The result for this query should be like this :

```
Date       | Product | purchases  | sales  | Stock
-----------+---------+------------+--------+-------
2019-08-31 | P1      |     2      |    1   |   2
2019-08-31 | P2      |    16      |   16   |   1
```

i have tried this query but it gave me bad results : 
WITH SumZ as (select sum(purchases)-sum(sales) as stock from t 
    WHERE t.date < DATEADD(DAY, -(DAY(GETDATE())), GETDATE()))

SELECT date ,Product, purchases, sales , SumZ.stock 
FROM t , SumZ
WHERE date  BETWEEN DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0) 
       AND DATEADD(DAY, -(DAY(GETDATE())), GETDATE())

Comment: How do *you* define "last month"?

Comment: this month is 2019-09 last month would be  2019-08 , like in the the example

Comment: What have you tried so far???

Comment: i should have put what i have tried in the question , i edited it again to show want i have tried

Comment: @Eric  any thoughts on the problem ?

Comment: @chawky What's wrong with Gordon's solution?  I think it should give the answer you want.

Comment: @Eric that query for SQL server 2012 and above i think , but turns out that my client's sql server is 2008 so eomonth does not exist there and to replace it i need to write a script which will make things even more complecated

Answer (score 2):

You seem to want an aggregation query with filtering:

```
select eomonth(date), product, sum(purchases), sum(sales),
         sum(purchases) - sum(sales)
from t
where eomonth(date) = eomonth(dateadd(month, -1, getdate()))
group by eomonth(date), product;
```

EDIT:

For a cumulative sum for `stock`, you can do:

```
select dp.*
from (select eomonth(date) as date, product,
             sum(purchases) as purchases, sum(sales) as sales,
             sum(sum(purchases) - sum(sales)) over (partition by product order by eomonth(date) as stock
      from t
      group by eomonth(date), product
     ) dp
where eomonth(date) = eomonth(dateadd(month, -1, getdate()));
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b29b55024c919bff4191c3cce6cd2cbf) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: i got this error : The text, ntext, and image data types cannot be compared or sorted, except when using IS NULL or LIKE operator.

Comment: @chawky . . . You should not be using any of those types for any of these columns.  In fact, you should not be using them for *any* columns (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/ntext-text-and-image-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).  Fix your data!

Comment: i fixed my data but it gave me wrong results : for P1 the stock was 1 when it shouldve been 2 and for P2 the stock was 0 when it should have been 1 as for purchases and sales and date the results were good

Comment: @ Gordon Linoff  in you query the stock is calculated only for the previous month when it should be calculated for all months up untill the last day of last month

Comment: @chawky . . . That clarifies what you want to do.  You need a window function.  I updated the answer.

Comment: @ Gordon Linoff thank you , but there is still an error for P1 its still giving me 1 when it should be giving me 2 but for P2 its worked it gave me 1 and its the good result

Comment: @chawky . . . Right idea.  Wrong implementation.  The filtering goes *after* the cumulative sum.  So, a subquery is needed.

Comment: @ Gordon Linoff this time it gave 3 in stock for P1 and P2

Comment: @ Gordon Linoff any luck with this problem ?

Comment: it's very difficult , i couldnt find an answer

Comment: @chawky . . .It is working now.  I added a db<>fiddle and fixed the code.

Comment: @ Gordon Linoff i was so happy when that query worked , but nothing lasts forever , turns out the client's sql server manager that they use is 2007 so that query didnt not work :/

Comment: Still no luck with this issue , eomont does not exist in SQL server 2008 and i saw that i have to create a script to replace it , any help ? @Gordon Linoff

Comment: @chawky . . . SQL Server 2008 is no longer supported as a product at all.  You should upgrade to a supported product.

Comment: it is not me who's using it , it is my client and i need to query his database   :/

Comment: can you please help i still need the data from the client